# How to make a sub method of a method in Python

Tags: python

Just like in pandas `df.plot()` is a method, `df.plot.bar()` is a method of `df.plot`.
Or in PyQt5 `button.clicked()` and `button.cliked.connect()`.

I saw their .pyi files. They are just written as `def plot(self, ...)` or `def clicked(self, ...)` like other normal methods, not a subclass. I wonder how to implement such an effect.

Comment: in pandas `bar` is a method of the class PlotAccessor in pandas.plotting and the pandas DataFrame has `plot = CachedAccessor("plot", pandas.plotting.PlotAccessor)`. So when you do `df.plot()` you are creating a CachedAccessor object with self._accessor being the class PlotAcessor and when you do df.plot.bar() you are using a method of the class PlotAcessor

Comment: just adding that the `__get__` method of CachedAccessor returns `self._accessor(obj)`, wchich is a PlotAccessor object